# How to use touch released on android?

Tags: java, android, html

I am creating my first game with android studio, everything is fine but the only problem is I can use OnTouch button but when I use touch release its not working, this is my code

```
button  OnTouchEnd="accelerate(-0.2)" OnTouchStart="accelerate(0.05)" ACCELERATE button
```

Ontouchstart is working but Ontouchend is not, I have already checked Ontouchrelease, Ontouchcancel, Onmouseup also, one important thing this is in my html file in assets folder and I am using Webview.

What type of code I have to use ?